# Add safeGet method to Sized from Shapeless

Tags: list, scala, type-safety, shapeless

I set about adding a safeGet method to Sized because I felt it was what would be best for some client code I am working on.

I was able to get it to work with an awful hack that works in my case but not in the general case.

This is the method signature and definition:

```
def safeGet(m : Nat)(implicit diff : Diff[L, Succ[m.N]], ev : ToInt[m.N]) = r(toInt[m.N])
```

However, there are a few additional hacks that must be performed for this to work because Traversable does not define the apply method. Here is the full (small) diff: https://github.com/jedesah/shapeless/commit/ab52185bec7463f54a040e7857cba7c5758fe46e

Anyone have any ideas how I could get the same result in a more appropriate way?

I feel like there would have to be an IsGenSeqLike in the standard library for this to be done correctly. Then I could leave Traversable alone and only define safeGet on Seq.

Comment: You can't just add an implicit class to some `Sized` class for this to work?

Comment: Actually, ya possibly, I will try that out when I get a chance.